# SAS Oracle Data Issues

Tags: oracle, sas

I'm having an issue regarding special characters. I use SAS to connect to an Oracle database and then download tables from Oracle to SAS datasets.

Previously, special characters where downloaded correctly without a problem. I've recently received a new laptop at work and since then there has been some data issues.

Basically, what is happening is that special characters are removed or completely replaced. For instance, é is being replaced by e. á replaced with a. Other special characters are just completely removed and replaced with '?'

I've read a bunch of articles about encoding, transcoding and NLS_LANGUAGE, but I just can't figure out why this is happening and how to fix it. My other colleagues who are still using old laptops do not have this same issue!

Please, any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: What are the NLS settings for server and client? What happens if you query the database with SQL*Plus from your laptop?

Comment: Well, if I connect to the database from my laptop using SQL Developer, I can see that the special characters are there in the database. If I connect with SAS and view them as datasets, they are gone.

Here are some of the NLS DATABASE PARAMETERS

NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Comment: Will this help - http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0209b&L=sas-l&P=26341

Comment: I think that points me closer to the right direction. I don't see the system variable on my laptop, but I don't see on my colleagues' laptops either.

Comment: If you are still having problems, post back with more detail.  In what ways are your old and new PCs different (operating system and SAS version)?  If you only have this problem from inside SAS, it's likely a configuration file setting.

Comment: It appears to me that while installing SAS in your new laptop, the correct language options were not selected. See page 3 of the doc - http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/unicode913.pdf - you can first check and try modifying the SASV9.CFG file as suggested in pages 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Windows Registry. On my machine the setting is at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\oracle\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\NLS_LANG`. Compare this key to that of coworkers who use SAS w/ Oracle and still have the older laptops.